# Parse json file with ironpython 2.5

Tags: json, ironpython, spotfire

I am using IronPython 2.5 (inside TIBCO Spotfire) and would like to parse a json file.

The json library is not available in this version of IronPython.   simplejson doesn't work either.  Is there another library i can use for this? It can be .Net or Python, doesn't matter.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I figured it out...

convert the json string to a dictionary:

```
jsonstring = open('myfile.json').read()
data = eval(jsonstring)
```

Comment: Does not work if your json file contains boolean values, i.e true/false

Answer (score 7):

I have also done it with `JavaScriptSerializer`. As follows:

```python
peopleJson = '''[
    {"name":"Jon", "age": "29", canSing:false, favColors:["red", "white"]},
    {"name":"Lilly", "age": "55", "canSing": true}
]'''
#convert json to string
import clr
clr.AddReference('System.Web.Extensions')
from System.Web.Script.Serialization import JavaScriptSerializer
people = JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(peopleJson)

for person in people:
    # each line is a dictionary
    print person['name'] + ' ' + person['age']
```

The output is:

```
Jon 29
Lilly 55
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the common choices for JSON in .NET is [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json). I have successfully used it from IronPython and depending on your use-case you should be able to deserialize to an object model or just load JObjects <strike>and use LINQ to query the data you need</strike>. LINQ probably won't work seamlessly as you will not be able to (properly) `clr.ImportExtensions` in IronPython prior to 2.7.

Please also look at [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/799215/468244).